# Transition from Jenkins to Github Actions

Tags: jenkins, migration, github-actions

We have a couple of Jenkins instances with over 400 hundred jobs. Although it is used as CI tool, it is fairly complex due to all integrations and number of services.
We have three repositories to use with Jenkins:

1. Job DSLs with job definitions
2. Shared library with most (there is a number of custom pipelines defined in Jenkinsfiles) of the pipeline definitions
3. JCasC

While I am all for progress, I am a bit reluctant to transition to Github Actions as it would not only take a lot of time, but the complexity achieved with Jenkins might not be so easy to achieve with Github Actions.
Nonetheless the decision has been made by management to cut the costs of Jenkins maintenance.

**Anyone who went down that road, was it complex as it seems?
Did you manage to achieve the same level of customisation and abstraction with GH as is possible with Jenkins?**

I have experience with Github Actions, but is limited on smaller apps, and I definitely don't have experience with GH for complex systems.

Comment: Sure, it's a bit of hoke-poke, but you can use the proprietary microsoft github actions service to run a github action that triggers the jenkins build. No idea who needs that, but YMMV, therefore check the market: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/trigger-jenkins-job

Comment: I just edited my question to add the reason for migration. When thinking in the direction of reusing existing Jenkins bits, but loosing the Jenkins instance itself, _Jenkins Single-shot masters_ are a far more feasible idea: [jenkinsfile-runner-github-actions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner-github-actions), but still on kind of a POC level with GH...

Answer (score 2):

While the migration from Jenkins to GitHub Actions is [officially documented](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions) (and, as noted by [Benjamin W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) in [the comments](https://benjamin-w), assisted [by automatic import](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer)), it entails the following difficulties:

1. Code access: Jenkins is self-hosted and can access self-hosted code.
   Unless your code is already on GitHub, a GitHub Action would not be able to access the same self-hosted code to check it out on its runner.
   Using [GHE (GitHub for Enterprise)](https://github.com/enterprise), you could use [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners)... but then that would be equivalent to your current Jenkins setup.

Simply hosting your code on GitHub is not always possible for confidential, proprietary enterprise code.

2. Jenkins plugins: you would have to re-implement them into a corresponding GitHub Action, or check if there is [one already matching your need](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions)
3. Publication: a GitHub Action can store the result of its pipeline [as an artifact](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts). Again, depending on the sensitive nature of an enterprise project, that may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: Additionally, there's a [GitHub CLI extension to import Jenkins pipelines](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer).